# Can't find solution for insert many with using cte

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Hi I have next sql code:

```
with cte as (select max(idmilityattache)
             from dopinfo.milityattaches)
insert
into dopinfo.milityattaches
values ((select * from cte) + 1, 1, 'a', '2023-03-02'::date, 'a'),
       ((select * from cte) + 2, 1, 'a', '2023-03-02'::date, 'a')
```

I need write it on sqlalchemy, but rows like this ((select * from cte) + 2, 1, 'a', '2023-03-02'::date, 'a') can be N, so I need get it on sqlalchemy Core or Orm and index(max + 1) which I add should range in 1 to N where N is number of rows to insert.

I tried code like this but it didn't work

```
attaches_values = [
            {
                Milityattache.nameemployee: literal(self.validated['fio']),
                Milityattache.idmilitaryrank: literal(self.validated['mr']),
                Milityattache.datestart: literal(self.validated['datestart']),
                Milityattache.telefons: literal(self.validated['telefons']),
                Milityattache.idmilityattache: self.session.query(
                    case(
                        [(func.max(Milityattache.idmilityattache).isnot(None),
                          func.max(Milityattache.idmilityattache) + num)], else_=literal(value=num)
                        )
                    ).scalar()
            }
            for num in range(1, len(self.validated['country'])+1)
        ]
        res = self.session.execute(
            insert(
                Milityattache

            ).values(
                attaches_values
            ).returning(
                Milityattache.idmilityattache
            )
        )
```

So i found solution to my problem:

```
max_id_cte = self.session.query(
        case(
            [(func.max(Milityattache.idmilityattache).isnot(None),
              func.max(Milityattache.idmilityattache) + 1)], else_=literal(value=1)
        ).label("m")
    ).cte("cte")

    ins = insert(
        Milityattache,
        [
            {
                'nameemployee': self.validated['fio'],
                'idmilitaryrank': self.validated['mr'],
                'datestart': self.validated['datestart'],
                'telefons': self.validated['telefons'],
                'idmilityattache': select([max_id_cte.c.m + _id])
            }
            for _id in range(len(self.validated['country']))
        ]
    ).returning(Milityattache.idmilityattache)
```

Comment: I am using Postgresql for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found solution to my problem:

```
max_id_cte = self.session.query(
        case(
            [(func.max(Milityattache.idmilityattache).isnot(None),
              func.max(Milityattache.idmilityattache) + 1)], else_=literal(value=1)
        ).label("m")
    ).cte("cte")

    ins = insert(
        Milityattache,
        [
            {
                'nameemployee': self.validated['fio'],
                'idmilitaryrank': self.validated['mr'],
                'datestart': self.validated['datestart'],
                'telefons': self.validated['telefons'],
                'idmilityattache': select([max_id_cte.c.m + _id])
            }
            for _id in range(len(self.validated['country']))
        ]
    ).returning(Milityattache.idmilityattache)
```